# How to execute commands in container from Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, rancher

I'm new in rancher/docker world, and i am  trying to find the best way to execute commands from Jenkins in an existing container (mainly bash and php commands), in order to use Jenkins as a job scheduler.

In my old infra, i was doing this by using "Execute SSH on a remote server". But i read that's it's not the best way to achieve this when using docker, and that's it's better to use docker exec.

So what'es your advice to achieve this ? At the moment, i was figuring those scenariis :

1. Installing openssh server on my app container, and SSH it from Jenkins using a link
2. SSH on the host where the container app is running and use "docker exec" . But the difficulty will be to know where the container is hosted everytime the build is running in Jenkins
3. Any ideas ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Can you provide a use case where you want to run a command inside of a container rather than calling an api of the running app or creating a new container?

Comment: Sure, for example, command like php artisan some::method which are batch written in PHP Laravel, or simple php (php -q myscript.php)